# Problem using shift function to compare with previous row values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

This is my function:

```
def shift_turn(data):
    data['AUX'] = np.where(data['Status'] == 'Offline', '1', '0')
    data['AUX'] = np.where((data['DateTimeBegin corrected'] < data['CAP']) & (data['Status'] != 'Offline'), 0, data['AUX'])
    data['AUX'] = np.where((data.ShortLogin == data.ShortLogin.shift()) & (data.Status.shift() == 'Offline') & (data['DateTimeBegin corrected'] >= data['CAP']), 1, data['AUX'])
    data['AUX'] = np.where((data.ShortLogin == data.ShortLogin.shift()) & (data.AUX.shift() == 1), 1, data['AUX'])

    return data
```

And for this example I'm retrieving this;

```
CCMSID  ShortLogin  Status  DateTimeBegin corrected DateTimeEnd corrected   CAP AUX
38  3808806 ABCM    Offline 2021-10-11 00:00:00 2021-10-11 08:00:00 2021-10-12 05:00:00 1
39  3808806 ABCM    Meeting 2021-10-11 08:00:00 2021-10-11 09:25:00 2021-10-12 05:00:00 0
40  3808806 ABCM    Moderation Task 2021-10-11 09:25:00 2021-10-11 10:20:00 2021-10-12 05:00:00 0
41  3808806 ABCM    Rest    2021-10-11 10:20:00 2021-10-11 10:35:00 2021-10-12 05:00:00 0
42  3808806 ABCM    Moderation Task 2021-10-11 10:35:00 2021-10-11 11:35:00 2021-10-12 05:00:00 0
43  3808806 ABCM    Meeting 2021-10-11 11:35:00 2021-10-11 12:00:00 2021-10-12 05:00:00 0
44  3808806 ABCM    Meeting 2021-10-11 13:00:00 2021-10-11 15:10:00 2021-10-12 05:00:00 0
45  3808806 ABCM    Rest    2021-10-11 15:10:00 2021-10-11 15:20:00 2021-10-12 05:00:00 0
46  3808806 ABCM    Meeting 2021-10-11 15:20:00 2021-10-11 17:00:00 2021-10-12 05:00:00 0
47  3808806 ABCM    Offline 2021-10-11 17:00:00 2021-10-12 08:00:00 2021-10-12 05:00:00 1
48  3808806 ABCM    Meeting 2021-10-12 08:00:00 2021-10-12 09:20:00 2021-10-12 05:00:00 1
49  3808806 ABCM    Moderation Task 2021-10-12 09:20:00 2021-10-12 10:00:00 2021-10-12 05:00:00 1
50  3808806 ABCM    Rest    2021-10-12 10:00:00 2021-10-12 10:15:00 2021-10-12 05:00:00 0
51  3808806 ABCM    Moderation Task 2021-10-12 10:15:00 2021-10-12 10:18:00 2021-10-12 05:00:00 0
52  3808806 ABCM    Meeting 2021-10-12 10:18:00 2021-10-12 11:00:00 2021-10-12 05:00:00 0
```

The problem that I am having with my code is that in the lines 50, 51 and 52 I was expecting to retrieve 1 and not 0, in the column AUX, has it is showing.

```
data['AUX'] = np.where((data.ShortLogin == data.ShortLogin.shift()) & (data.AUX.shift() == 1), 1, data['AUX'])
```

I thought using this line, the code was going to see where ShortLogin is equal to previous row ShortLogin and AUX previous row equal 1, and if yes it would give 1 if not would do nothing.

Any suggestion to overcome this issue?

Also open to more efficient ways build up my function.

Thanks in advance!